# Why don't questions from the religious SE sites ever show up in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Not once have I seen a question from a religious Stack Exchange site show up in the "Hot questions" side bar, and I've been keeping an eye out for over a year now.

Is it because the Stack Exchange network doesn't want to spark controversy by including religious questions? Personally I would love to see a hot question from Christianity.SE pop up every now and then.

The same applies for Mi Yodeya, the Islam, and Hinduism SE sites. Why does nothing from there ever show up in the side bar?

Perhaps you guys are using an automatic algorithm to select the hot questions? In which case I would like to know why this algorithm is discriminating against the religious sites.

Comment: Maybe, religious questions are not that popular overall

Answer (score 16):

Different sites get different amounts of "heat" so to speak; some subjects just don't attract the sorts of fast-and-furious attention needed to spend a lot of time on the list.

That said, they do show up, even if not for very long. Here are the numbers for the past 90 days:

```
Site                        Inbound clicks from the HNQ lists 
--------------------------- ---------------------------------
Mi Yodeya                   82                                          
Christianity Stack Exchange 109                                         
Islam Stack Exchange        44                                          
Buddhism Stack Exchange     51                                          
Hinduism Stack Exchange     159
```

For comparison, here are the same numbers for five other sites that get similar numbers of questions per day:

```
Site                               Inbound clicks from the HNQ lists 
---------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Video Production Stack Exchange    2                                           
Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange 6                                           
Craft CMS Stack Exchange           11                                          
Ethereum Stack Exchange            22                                          
Internet of Things Stack Exchange  132
```

Answer (score 6):

If you had searched for "hot questions" on meta.christianity (where you cross-posted this question), you would have come across the previous discussion of why Christianity.SE used to be "penalized" in terms of showing up on the HNQ list:

https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5713/889

The same answer states that the "penalty" was removed in October 2015.  So it's just a matter of answering and voting patterns that limits how many Christianity.SE questions show up.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, the Christianity Stack Exchange site was penalized on the HNQ list, [but that is no longer the case](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5713/21576).  Since the penalty was removed (October 2015), I have personally had many of my questions on Christianity.SE reach the HNQ list, as shown here:

> > [image]