# Why is this recent question not in the active list?

Tags: bug, question-lists

[My question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290009/339911) was asked 12 hours ago and then modified two hours ago. But I can't see it in the list in the "active" tab. Is it due to minus 8 score? The tooltip says:

> [image: Active tooltip]

The question was asked and updated recently. So why can't I see my question in this list?

Possibly related question: [Can't see my own question in the hot list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288933/339911)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it has dropped below the -8 threshold score. Questions scoring lower are excluded from that view.

Comment: Where I can read about this? Worth noting that **-8** is not below, is equal.

Comment: I think you can find it [here on the SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). It is a very old post, but the general outline will be the same. (It says "drop questions scoring -4 or lower", that is site-configurable now)

Comment: Article is about replacing `active` tab with `interesting` one, and only for SO. `active` tab behavior should not change. Moreover, [question with minus 6](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290026/339911) score is still visible in the list.

Comment: -6 is not -8....

Comment: I think that logic is being used on more places. Note that the post is 7 years old. A lot has changed in the meantime.

Comment: Now, my question has `-7`and it become visible. :)

Comment: I told you so... :)

Comment: Nevertheless tooltip for `active` tab should be fixed.

Comment: Why? Should they show all thresholds that cause a question to come in that list?

Comment: Not all, but a general one, e.g.: `... and no downvoted too much`

Comment: The view is mainly for not-that-experienced users, experienced users know their way around. Just keep it simple.

Comment: I'm still not experienced user ... :(